# ruby on rails how to kill the resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, worker

I run the crawler in resque queue.It's a crawler and fetch information into the database...
I want to stop it ..
then I start the console in the server I use the commands:

```
irb(main):001:0> Resque.working[0].id
=> "09ec127d-bb90-4629-a6f2-bb2610885ab5:62:*"
irb(main):003:0> Resque.remove_worker("09ec127d-bb90-4629-a6f2-bb2610885ab5:62:*")
=> 0
```

Although in the /resque page...it shows no worker is running...but I found in the database is increasing....It is still writing data into the database..

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I kill my workers :

```
pids = Array.new

puts "Killing resque workers ... "
Resque.workers.each do |worker|
  pids << worker.to_s.split(/:/).second
end

if pids.size > 0
   system("kill -QUIT #{pids.join(' ')}")
end
```

Comment: Do i need to upload the code?  Can I use the command in the console to kill them?

Comment: @linzilan try http://www.kensodev.com/2011/09/17/kill-all-resque-workers-with-a-single-command/

Comment: @linzilan, in your example you were in IRB. It's safe to say that this answer assumes you have some experience in IRB or the Rails console.